# Maintaining Right Order with Event Grid, Functions & Service Bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid, ordered-delivery

Our event workflow works like this.

Publishing System --> Event Grid --> Azure Function (Durable) --> Service Bus --> Consuming App

Now for a new requirement, we need to maintain the order of events/messages, so based on whatever was received first by Event Grid, consuming app should receive it in the same order.

What can we do in Event Grid, Function and Service Bus so this order is maintained?

Note: Azure Function is used in the middle to fetch the details about the event by calling an API.

Comment: Is it a must to have Eventgrid? And is it a must to have Service bus at the end? If you replace Event grid with Service bus and switch sessions on, you can ensure ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Grid doesn't guarantee ordering https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry, however from Service Bus you can use sessions to receive messages in order from the Consuming App https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Service Bus sessions look promising, we'll try them out. I forgot to add that events actually don't come directly to Event Grid, publisher actually posts them to an endpoint in APIM from where we create them in Event Grid (using code in policy) so same thing will happen even if we use Service Bus Sessions, is there anyway to ensure APIM is maintaining order?

Comment: APIM should maintain the order as events are coming in, the problem here is in between Event grid and the function app, if you are sending messages sequencially you will likely see they come in order, but sometimes the function might not reply to EG within 30 seconds and the messages from EG side gets enqueued for retry, in those particular cases you will lose ordering as another message will be pushed to the Function while the other message is waiting to be retried.

Comment: I can see event grid schema contains time stamp (event date) so in case of retrying would the event grid property event date get changed to a newer date (lose the order), or would the event date property maintains the date when we received this message and in such scenario order can still be guaranteed